What is meant by "God's Omnibenevolence"?
I am wondering what people mean by God having omnibenevolence. I see it having a couple meanings; one being God loves all, which I agree with. Another one is if God is all good, which obviously He is. He created the morality and is above it. He decides what is good and what is bad. Or people good mean He is infinitely kind. Kindness according to the oxford dictionary is

"the quality of being friendly, generous, and considerate."

I would argue that God is not infinitely kind, otherwise there would be no hell. or perhaps people mean something completely different. What's the general consensus?
edit: i probably just don't understand something

I once tried starting my day without thanking God for all his blessings.  It went badly!  Unrelated, but you might like to take our Tour: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Whoa, slow down buddy. Omnibenovelent means he is also accountable which means he needs to punish those who broke his laws. So this argument is null and void

@SoFewAgainstSoMany I dont believe i understand. what do you mean by omnibenevolent? thats probably where the misunderstanding happens. isnt it possible to be kind without necessarily being right and being right isnt necessarily being kind?

@pyrotechn1cs,  imagine a world without laws , even scientific laws like gravity. There could be chaos , it's the same with God he has laws which also are an extension of his good nature , and part of that omnibenovelent is ensuring those who abused his kindness are brought to book.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany So is God's omnibenevolence being all kind and not all generous?

@Pyrotechn1cs, laws are good because the law of gravity is preventing your house from floating into space. Laws are part of that omnibenovelence you were inquiring about.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Okay that makes a lot more sense. I think I agree with you. Thank you!

@Pyrotechn1cs, anytime brother.

I am not sure that "omni-benevolence" is a way to describe God. There are many scriptures that directly say that God "hates" or "detests" this or that. So it is not an "Omni".

There are six things that the Lord hates, seven that are an abomination to him: haughty eyes, a lying tongue, and hands that shed innocent blood, a heart that devises wicked plans, feet that make haste to run to evil, a false witness who breathes out lies, and one who sows discord among brothers. (Proverbs 6:16-19)


The boastful shall not stand before your eyes; you hate all evildoers. (Psalm 5:5)


The fear of the Lord is hatred of evil. Pride and arrogance and the way of evil and perverted speech I hate. (Proverbs 8:13)


The Lord tests the righteous, but His soul hates the wicked and the one who loves violence. (Psalm 11:5)


For I the Lord love justice; I hate robbery and wrong; I will faithfully give them their recompense, and I will make an everlasting covenant with them. (Isaiah 61:8)

Among many other verses...
A proper way to think about it is something akin to
"God loves sinners, but hates sin"

that makes sense

As one tag is Reformed theology, I would suggest that omnibenevolence is not a teaching in the Protestant branch. It might be worth checking where this idea comes from. It certainly is not found in the Bible with respect to God. The only time the Greek word 'eunoia' (good mind) occurs is here:

"Let the husband render unto the wife due benevolence: and likewise
also the wife unto the husband." 1 Corinthians 7:3 A.V.

Nobody who is familiar with the Bible can avoid seeing what is said about the righteous judgment of God, especially that which will be rendered on the Day of Resurrection and Judgment. The wrath of God on unrepentant sinners is an unavoidable fact in the Bible, and that is taught in Reformed groups. See 1 Thessalonians 1:10, Romans 2:5, John 3:36.
If you discover where this idea of God being omnibenevolent originated, then the question could be progressed, and explanations given as to what those who believe in it is supposed to mean, but there's no substance for it in Reformed circles.
EDIT:  A Got Questions link on this subject says, "To believe in a perfect being, one must accept that God can be omnibenevolent." Notice "can"? Notice switching the meaning of 'benevolence' to 'goodness'? Yes, God is "all good", but his perfect goodness is not mere benevolence! That is to see God in human terms of what humans think it is to be 'good' - benevolent people must therefore be good people. Pride can then creep in: "I'm a good person because I'm like God - I'm benevolent - I spread my good gifts and benefits around."
God's being perfectly good does not equate with mere benevolence. This recent claim about God being omnibenevolent has led to philosophers contesting it due to God’s perfect justice. They see a clash. Of course they do. They’ve latched on to this unbiblical claim in triumph, arguing that it clashes with God being utterly righteous and holy due to him punishing unrepentant sinners! Yet the Bible NOWHERE says God is all-benevolent.
Humans have recently made that claim, adding it to the actual ‘omni’ qualities of the only true God. It’s as if humans know they cannot equate themselves in any sense to God’s omni-qualities, so they’ve invented this new one so that they can.

The word omnibenevolent comes from the Latin word omni, meaning “all,” and the word benevolent, meaning “good” or “charitable.” In other words, God is absolutely good and no action or motive or thought or feeling or anything else about Him is not purely good. He is “all-good.”
This is the sense in which I understand God being omnibenevolent. The Bible reminds us of the overwhelming goodness of God:

Praise the Lord; for the Lord is good: sing praises unto his name; for it is pleasant. (Psalm 135:3 KJV)


Praise the Lord. O give thanks unto the Lord; for he is good: for his mercy endureth for ever. (Psalm 106:1 KJV)


The Lord is good, a strong hold in the day of trouble; and he knoweth them that trust in him. (Nahum 1:7)

The goodness, kindness and love of God is revealed to us in the person of Christ (Titus 3:1). It is the goodness and benevolence of God that leads us to repentance and salvation (Romans 2:4).
The overwhelming benevolence of God towards us is demonstrated in this:

That while we were still sinners, Christ died for us (Romans 5:8).

It would be wrong to conclude that God is so benevolent that He would turn a blind eye to sin but his character and nature demonstrate that no action or motive or thought or feeling or anything else about Him is not purely good.
This article examines the character and nature of God and helps to put the benevolence of God into perspective: https://www.gotquestions.org/character-of-God.html

That's a great link, not least because it does NOT say that God is omnibenevolent. The closest it gets to 'benevolence' is where is says God's expressions of His goodness [are] designed to benefit His people. Whatever translation was used re. Romans 2:4, I would just say that it speaks of the riches of God's goodness, forebearance and longsuffering (which is to lead to repentance). The next verse warns that those with hardened, impenitent hearts will experience the wrath of God's righteous judgment.  That does not support omnibenevolence!  But the link does show God's many characteristics.

@Anne Omnibenevolence is just a fancy term for "all good".  Isn't the Christian God said to be "all good, all powerful, and all knowing" (omnibenevolent, omnipotent, and omniscience) which creates a specifically Christian problem of evil?  Here's GotQuestion article on omnibenevolence.  I don't understand your objection to this standard attribute of God's being perfectly Good.

@GratefulDisciple Having read that link, I have to flag up "To believe in a perfect being, one must accept that God can be omnibenevolent." Notice "can"? Notice switching the meaning of 'benevolence' to 'goodness'? I agree that God is "all good", but his perfect goodness is not mere benevolence! That is to see God in human terms of what humans think is to be 'good' - benevolent people must therefore be good people. Pride can then creep in: "I'm a good person because I'm like God - I'm benevolent - I spread my good gifts and benefits around." God's being perfectly good does not equate with mere


The Lord is good to all; he has compassion on all he has made. - Psalm
145:9

The extent of God's love in scope is universal. No person whom God has created has not received love from God.
The extent of God's love in time is eternal for the elect. Once the elect receive their new bodies as they enter eternity and live in Heaven (or on the new earth, as some teach), no further discipline, suffering, deprivation or pain will again enter their experience.
The extent of God's love in time is limited for the reprobate. They receive blessings to different degrees in this life, but when it ends they pass under judgment and endure eternal torment. While in Hell, they continue to experience the benevolence of God, but it is no comfort to them. This benevolence consists in removing all possibility of causing harm to any elect persons. This means that they can add no more crimes to their account, so the level of their punishment will not increase. Since the impulse of the sinner to do evil continually, the trend would be to increase their debt for all eternity. By limiting this, God prevents these sinners from driving their accounts further in the red, earning for themselves ever harsher penalties.

Laws are an intrinsic part of any creation, you understand how laws are important from the created world. You can start with scientific laws like gravity, imagine a world without the law of gravity , that implies chaos and no order. God instituted order by establishing laws that govern the created universe. Your house is intact because of the law of gravity. The same applies with God, when he created us, (creation by itself was an act of omnibenovelence if you ask me).
Similar to the natural world which has laws that govern it's interactions ,  God gave man laws that govern our interactions with him, and unlike the created world which subscribe to these laws by force, humanity was given a free will to choose. The computer your typing this post on is able to service you because it obeys some electronic laws, God's omnibenovelence means he is also fair which means the rewards of the obedient and the rebellious won't be the same.
Those who are condemned to hell refused God's gift of eternal life which is another act of omnibenovelence, humankind didn't deserve this gift of living forever but God out of mercy and grace has sent his own Son to beg them to be like Him so they may be heirs but some have obeyed and some have rebelled, the rewards won't be the same, omnibenovelence itself demands that those who are rebellious be punished and the obedient rewarded, it's called fairness.
